Fetch a list sorted by latest change based on multiple joined columns
I have a Persons table and other tables related - Orders, ContactHistory, Addresses, and Emails.
The Persons table has basic details - name, date of birth, and a few other properties.
The class for the table has collections for the tables referenced by the Persons table, so, I can use them in filters where needed or query referenced.
All those tables have Updated property that is set on every update.
I need to return a page of results ordered descendingly by the latest change.
So, if somebody changes the address for a person, changes their name, or contacts the person, all those actions should move the person to the top.
The base part of my query looks like
var result = await _context
                .Persons
                .Include(p => p.Addresses)
                .Include(p => p.Emails)
                .Include(p => p.Orders)
                .Include(p => p.ContactHistory)
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Updated)
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToArrayAsync();

I need to change OrderByDescending(p => p.Updated) to include the other tables.
I cannot use ThenBy as this will not work - every next part will order the data only when all the previous dates are the same.
I need something like OrderByDescending(p => Max(p.Updated, p.Addresses.Updated, p.Emails.Updated ... and so on))
I am considering writing a SQL Server function and calling it from the C# code with EF Core if I cannot find a solution.
An example of how I would do it in T-SQL:
select distinct top 10 p.* from persons p
  inner join Addresses a on p.id = a.PersonId
  inner join Emails e on p.id = e.PersonId
  inner join Orders o on p.id = o.PersonId
  inner join ContactHistory c on p.id = c.PersonId
order by (select max(updated) from (values(p.Updated), (a.Updated),
  (e.Updated), (o.Updated), (c.Updated)) t(updated))

It is not the most efficient query, unfortunately, but the business needs demand that logic.
I am also open to other suggestions on how to tackle this problem - maybe there is a pattern I don't know about or something else.

I'm no expert, but perhaps you can create some scalar function which accepts some dates and return the largest? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping It won't be superflexible since functions cannot have variable parameter sizes

To calculate the combined latest Updated date, the logic needs to scan the entire parent/child tree consisting of multiple one-to-many joins. You might need to define and maintain an CombinedLastUpdated column in your Person table that is recalculated using triggers whenever any of the dependent tables are updated. (Deletes would be an interesting case. Do you want to record the time of delete or back up to the latest surviving Updated date?) There might also be a way to do this with a persistent computed column or view. The goal is to avoid expensive calculations just to sort.

Follow-up on my above: I did not have any luck creating a schemabound, indexed view as suggested above. Because the calculation involves subqueries, This db<>fiddle shows my attempt. Without the index, ordering by CombinedLastUpdated requires a full scan of all of the data, which is extremely inefficient. A persisted computed column also has limitations that prevent subqueries. I believe the trigger-maintained column may be the best option. If you don't care about performance, an on-the-fly calculation is the fall back.

@siggemannen - Do you mean like GREATEST()?  Unfortunately, that is not yet in the current EF SQL Server function mappings.

@TN no, I meant he could make own scalar function

Side note: Your "how I would do it" example above is using inner joins. If there is a possibility that one or more child tables has no matching rows for a given Person ID, these would need to be left joins. Any answer to this question would also need to handle such cases. I expect they would also need to accommodate multiple rows from any child table.

I removed the SQL Server tag since you are asking for an EF Core solution. If you have an  issue with the SQL solution then post another question.

@siggemannen - I am considering a function, it is in the post. This would be if I don't find a better solution

@DaleK I added the tag as there is potentially different code for different databases in Entity framework. I had differences, for example, when I did a full-text search for EF-core SQL server and EF-core PostgreSQL, but, yes, sure, this is not a pure SQL server question, I just didn't find a matching tag.

@Mykola you shouldn't need database specific features unless you get into raw sql.

@TN you are very right - the query is not super efficient, I am looking into options to improve it, when I call the raw SQL as a research, it is quite slow now. Using triggers, unfortunately, is not the way to go, as it will change the Version column and the updates on the Person table will most likely fail if we are tracking concurrency. Even worse, if it fails sometimes... But thanks for the suggestion.

@Mykola, maybe you need efficient SaveChanges hook, which will update Person's LastUpdate or similar field when any of these entries changed?

Try the following query. It prepares information with last update for each person. Then joins to your original query and make appropriate order.
// append filters
var personsQuery = _context.Persons;

var orderQuery = 
    from p in personsQuery
    from e in p.Emails
    from o in p.Orders
    from h in p.ContactHistory
    group new { p, e, o, h } by p.Id into g
    select new 
    {
        PersonId = g.Key,
        LastUpdated = g.Max(x => Math.Max(x.p.Updated, Math.Max(x.e.Updated, Math.Max(x.o.Updated, x.h.Updated))))
    }

orderQuery = orderQuery
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdate)
    .Take(10);

var query = personsQuery
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .Include(p => p.Emails)
    .Include(p => p.Orders)
    .Include(p => p.ContactHistory);

query = 
    from q in query
    join o in orderQuery on q.Id equals o.PersonId
    orderby o.LastUpdated descending
    select q;


var result = await query    
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();



That's quite a solution! Thank you! As @TN assumed in comments to the question, I do have some left join queries, so, I will look into changing the query to handle this - and nulls. Also, Math.Max didn't work for me as the type of the columns is DateTimeOffset, but I didn't specify it in the question. The speed is on a similar level to the reference SQL I have.

Well, we can try use functionGREATEST. It's translation should be trivial.

@Mykola - To get the max for a set of DateTimeOffset values, you really only care about the underlying UTC date/time. Changing all .Updated references to .Updated.UtcDateTime  should work.

I am going to make a few assumptions:

Your intent is to retrieve the top N most recently changed person profiles as efficiently as possible:

Minimize trips to the database
Minimizing table data access by SQL server (avoid table scans)
Minimizing the amount of data transferred.


N will typically be much fewer than the overall person count.
You cannot change the table schema or add triggers, but can possibly add indexes.

I believe the best approach is to first construct a query that selects the top N most recent Person IDs using logic designed to execute entirely on the SQL Server side, with data transfer back to your application limited to the short list of selected Person IDs and associated last Updated dates.
Once you have that, you can use your original query (with minimal modifications) to retrieve just that data for those selected person IDs. This is a similar approach to Svyatoslav Danyliv's answer.
So the real trick trick is getting SQL Server to efficiently return the top updated Person IDs. The most obvious queries would likely cause SQL Server to perform table scans across all of the Person, Address, Email, and other tables. We would prefer to avoid that. I believe that with the proper covering indexes and a carefully crafted query, we can get what we want.
First, I would recommend covering indexes for all of the subject tables (including Person) in the form CREATE INDEX index_name ON table(Updated) INCLUDE(PersonId). This will at least limit data retrieval to an index scan instead of a table scan, but if we do things right, we might get SQL Server to only do an index range scan (or whatever the correct term is).
A theoretically efficient SQL query to obtain the top N updated person profiles would be something like:
DECLARE @N INT = 10

SELECT TOP (@N) U.PersonId, MAX(U.Updated) AS Updated
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@N) PersonId, Updated
    FROM Person
    ORDER BY Updated DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP (@N) PersonId, MAX(Updated) Updated
    FROM Address
    GROUP BY PersonId
    ORDER BY MAX(Updated) DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP (@N) PersonId, MAX(Updated) Updated
    FROM Email
    GROUP BY PersonId
    ORDER BY MAX(Updated) DESC

    -- UNION ALL for other tables
) U
GROUP BY U.PersonId
ORDER BY MAX(U.Updated) DESC

The hope is that each of the inner selects can be efficiently executed to obtain N PersonIds using the defined index without the need for an entire table scan or index scan, reading the index just far enough to get N unique PersonIds. Those results are then combined and the overall top N PersonIds are selected. (Think of the inner selects as heats in a track meet competition and the outer select as the final race.)
The next trick is to convert this to a LINQ query that translates to the above.
A tool that shall remain nameless, but whose results appear to be reasonable and have been heavily edited for readability, suggests the following:
int n = 10;

// Get most recently updated PersonIds from each person profile table
var personTopUpdatedPersons = Person
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Updated)
    .Take(n)
    .Select(p => new { p.PersonId, p.Updated });
var addressTopUpdatedPersons = Address
    .GroupBy(a => a.PersonId)
    .Select(g => new { PersonId = g.Key, Updated = g.Max(x => x.Updated) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
    .Take(n);
var emailTopUpdatedPersons = Email
    .GroupBy(e => e.PersonId)
    .Select(g => new { PersonId = g.Key, Updated = g.Max(x => x.Updated) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
    .Take(n);
// ... Others

// Combine the above to get the overall top N updated persons.
// Generate both a PersonId/Updated dictionary and PersonId list for later use.
var combinedTopUpdatedPersons = personTopUpdatedPersons
    .Concat(addressTopUpdatedPersons)
    .Concat(emailTopUpdatedPersons)
    .Concat(...others...);
var topUpdatedPersonsDictionary = combinedTopPersonIds
    .GroupBy(c => c.PersonId)
    .Select(g => new { PersonId = g.Key, Updated = g.Max(x => x.Updated) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
    .Take(N)
    .Select(x => x.PersonId)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.PersonId);  -- Dictionary of {PersonId, Updated}
var selectedPersonsIdList = topUpdatedPersonsList.Keys.ToList();

The above produces both a PersonId/Updated dictionary and a selected PersonId list. The list can be used to feed the .Where() condition of the main query, while the dictionary is needed to perform the final .OrderByDescending() for the final results.
var result = _context
                .Persons
                .Where(p => selectedPersonIdList.Contains(p.PersonID))
                .Include(p => p.Addresses)
                .Include(p => p.Emails)
                .Include(p => p.Orders)
                .Include(p => p.ContactHistory)
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .AsNoTracking()
                -- The above executes server-side (or in EF)
                -- The following executes client-side
                .OrderByDescending(p => topUpdatedPersonsDictionary(p.PersonId).Updated)
                .ToArray();

I do not yet have a test environment set up to try the above, so it is untested. You may need to tweak it and fix bugs, or it might not work at all.
One possible fallback if you cannot get the LINQ to function would be to just execute the raw SQL (with a parameter for N) or encapsulate it in a stored procedure.
Good luck.

For now, I added an empty interface to entities related to the Person entity and then processed the records on saving.
First I check if there is person being saved, and if so, I do not update the person's date as it is already set. I use ChangeTracker.Entries.
Then I pick the records affected with
        var processedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAffectsPersonSortOrder>()
            .Any();

and set the person's updated date via a separate asynchronous call using an Azure function.
I do not mark this as an answer as the workaround has nothing to do with Entity Framework, and it does not look super pretty. It will do for now, though.
